# "cancel" disapears after submit SearxhBox if the Text is set to null (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: button, null, searchbar, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control for to show the "cancel" button inside the iOS SearchBars:

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(AppSearchBarRenderer))]
    namespace Elfo.VisionMobile.iOS.Renderers
    {
        public class AppSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                Control.ShowsCancelButton = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my XAML:

```
    <SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchKey, Mode=TwoWay}" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
```

And the search execute method of the command (C#):

```
        private void SearchExecute()
        {
            // whatever...

            SearchKey = null;
        }
```

And when I set the SearchKey to null or string.Empty , the "cancel" button disapears.

Guys, do you know something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just fixed it.

I had to use the method `OnElementPropertyChanged` instead of `OnElementChanged`.